# Need help getting data from a file to use in a constructor(Java)

Tags: java

I am trying to get rid of the hard coded information, but I'm not sure how I would do it. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Chemical {

    private String chemName;
    private String chemFreezingPoint;
    private String chemBoilingPoint;
    private String chemUnitNumbers;


    public Chemical(String name, String freezingPoint, String boilingPoint, String unitNumbers){
    chemName = name;
    chemFreezingPoint = freezingPoint;
    chemBoilingPoint = boilingPoint;
    chemUnitNumbers = unitNumbers;
    }

    Chemical Ethanol        = new Chemical("Ethanol",         "-173",   "172",   "1575");
    Chemical Oxygen         = new Chemical("Oxygen",          "-363",   "-306",  "1000");
    Chemical Water          = new Chemical("Water",           "32",     "212",   "5000");
    Chemical Benzene        = new Chemical("Benzene",         "41.9",   "176.2", "2750");
    Chemical EthyleneGlycol = new Chemical("Ethylene Glycol", "8.78",   "378",   "1900");

    public static String[][] returnArray(){
        String[][] chemArray = {{"Ethanol","-173","172","1575"},{"Oxygen","-363","-306","1000"},{"Water","32","212","5000"},
                {"Benzene","41.9","176.2","2750"},{"Ethylene Glycol","8.78","378","1900"}};
        return chemArray;
    }

}
```

What I need help with is replacing the hard coded data with data I get from a text file. I will also need to use the data I get from the file in the 2D array I have coded also, but I am not sure on how to do either things as I've never read in data from a file before. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to read up on Properties, it's just what you are looking for. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Comment: Is Google down today?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt: Google is too hard, when you can type text into a box and get one or more people to respond to your text.

Answer (score 0):

To read lines from a text file you can use the BufferedReader class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html you can use the readln(); method to read the chemicals, and their information one line at a time. Also it would be more memory efficient to convert the strings for boiling point, e.t.c. to integers, and you could use separate arrays for each of the properties of the chemicals. However this shouldn't be an issue in small application such as this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file formatted like so:

```
ethanol,-173,172,1575
oxygen,-363,-306,1000
...
```

Then you can do this:

```
// Gotta put the file someplace
ArrayList<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>(0);

// Read the file into memory
String line;
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    contents.add(line);
}
bufferedReader.close();

// Create a dictionary (a HashMap) to hold the data
HashMap<String, Chemical> map = new HashMap<>();

// Load that Map with data
for (String line : contents) {
    String[] data = line.split(",")
    map.put(new Chemical(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]));
}
```